# Interface helpers or delegating interface parent

Tags: delphi, interface

If I have an existing `IInterface` descendant implemented by a third party, and I want to add helper routines, does Delphi provide any easy way to do so without redirecting every interface method manually?  That is, given an interface like so:

```
IFoo = interface
  procedure Foo1;
  procedure Foo2;
  ...
  procedure FooN;
end;
```

Is anything similar to the following supported?

```
IFooHelper = interface helper for IFoo
  procedure Bar;
end;
```

or

```
IFooBar = interface(IFoo)
  procedure Bar;
end;

TFooBar = class(TInterfacedObject, IFoo, IFooBar)
private
  FFoo: IFoo;
public
  procedure Bar;
  property Foo: IFoo read FFoo implements IFoo;
end;
```

I'm specifically wondering about ways to that allow me to always call Foo1, Foo2, and Bar with a single variable reference (IFoo, IFooBar, or TFooBar), without switching between them, and without adding all of IFoo's methods to TFooBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your class to read:

```
TFooBar = Class(TInterfacedObject, IFoo, IFooBar)
private
  FFoo: IFoo;
public
  procedure Bar;
  property Foo: IFoo read FFoo implements IFoo ;
end;
```

You will also need a constructor or some method to create the instance of IFoo and place it in FFoo.

Comment: The "class vs interface" and missing "read FFoo" were typos.  Even correcting them, the example doesn't work.  If I have a reference to TFooBar I can't call "FooBar.Foo1";  it's considered undeclared.

Comment: I believe you need to re-declare the procedures of IFoo in IFooBar if you want to use IFooBar and have them exposed.

Comment: Skamradt is right.  There's no "Interface helper" in Delphi.  It would be nice if there was, though.  Try adding it in QC.

Comment: I found a QC for a "interface helper" language feature in Delphi at: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=93289

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the methods of ***IFoo*** through a reference to *TFooBar* because *TFooBar* doesn't implement *IFoo* - it delegates *IFoo*.  But you shouldn't be using a *TFooBar* reference to access an interfaced object anyway, that's the whole point of using interfaces in the first place!

NOTE: To deliberately prevent this I adopt a convention of implementing interface methods on my classes as "protected", specifically to deny access to those implementation details except as surfaced via the interface itself.

Where-ever you are currently obtaining a reference to **TFooBar**, change this to instead obtain the ***IFooBar*** interface implemented by *TFooBar* and you will be sorted.

Comment: Apparently my post wasn't clear.  I have an 'IFoo' from a third party, which I don't control.  I'd like to add additional helper functions to it, like a class helper does.  TFooBar and IFooHelper were my proposed syntaxes for how this would occur.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood all of your concerns, but here's my suggestion anyway :

```
IFooBar = interface(IFoo)
  procedure Bar;
end;

TFooDelegate = class(TInterfacedObject, IFoo )
private
  FFoo: IFoo;
public
  property Foo: IFoo read FFoo implements IFoo;
end;

TFooBar = class( TFooDelegate, IFooBar )
  procedure Bar;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

see
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Implementing_Interfaces:_Delphi_and_C%2B%2B
on how to use TAggregatedObject together with "implements" syntax at a property

quoting from there:

```
unit Unit1;
 
 interface
 
 type
 
  // Interface that exposes an 'Add' method
  IAdder = interface
  ['{D0C74612-9E4D-459A-9304-FACE27E3577D}']
    function Add(I, J: Integer): Integer;
  end;
 
  // Aggregatee that implements IAdder
  TAdder = class(TAggregatedObject, IAdder)
    function Add(I, J: Integer): Integer;
  end;
 
  // Aggregator - implements IAdder via TAdder
  TPasClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IAdder)
    FAdder: TAdder;
    function GetAdder: TAdder;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Adder: TAdder read GetAdder write FAdder implements IAdder;
  end;
 
 function TestAdd(I, J: Integer): Integer; 
 
 implementation
 
 { TAdder }
 function TAdder.Add(I, J: Integer): Integer;
 begin
   Result := I+J;
 end;
 
 { TPasClass }
 destructor TPasClass.Destroy;
 begin
   FAdder.Free;
   inherited;
 end;
 
 function TPasClass.GetAdder: TAdder;
 begin
   if FAdder = nil then
     FAdder := TAdder.Create(Self as IInterface);
   Result := FAdder;
 end;
 
 // Adds using TClass' IAdder
 function TestAdd(I, J: Integer): Integer; 
 var
   punk: IInterface;
 begin
   punk := TPasClass.Create as IInterface;
   Result := (punk as IAdder).Add(I, J);
 end;
 
 end.
```

however it would be nice if one could do:

```
TSomeClassIFoo123Helper = class helper(IFoo1, IFoo2, IFoo3) for TSomeClass
  procedure Bar1;
  procedure Bar2;
  procedure Bar3;
end;
```

injecting IFoo1, IFoo2, IFoo3 interface implementations into TSomeClass. The helpers support inheritance, but can only specify another helper class at the list, not one ore more interfaces there